# Performance with PHP include()

Tags: php, include, session-variables

I have a PHP site that populates a session variable with filenames during login.  When the user brings up a certain page, the data contained in these files is included into the page.

From a performance standpoint, is there a better way to accomplish this?  I was thinking about loading the file data into the session array itself but wasn't sure if that would make any difference.

```
foreach($_SESSION['windows'] as $file)   
{  
    include("$file");
}
```

Comment: What do you know about performance? Why do you think you need to optimize this particular place?

Comment: It wholly depends on what your file's data look like. It might be better to have pointers (file paths) to those files stored and access them intelligently with a file handler to only access that data which you need at a specific time. It's a waste to load everything, in whatever way.

Comment: Unless you have tens of thousands of file names which are loaded in really slow ways (like through looping through the entire native file system), or you have millions of page views, the performance is so itty bitty tiny that I can't imagine a scenario where it's significant enough to even test.

Comment: Another note; If you files are quite big (2MB+, PHP memory won't lik e those) you might consider going for the `exec` method to access data in the files on the fly with search techniques like `grep`. It's solely a hint tho, as we don't know the purpose and scale of your situation.

Comment: @Allendar: how would you store file pointers?

Comment: @Allendar: where does the 2Mb number comes from?

Comment: @zerkms is this is prank? 2Mb is just a suggestion in my explanation, no fact. I do not mean to store file-pointers. He already knows his file-locations. Why load them fully each page load if only small pieces of that data is accessed each time? We both still know nothing about the details of the questions. I'm just pointing out viable options. By trying to nullify my means to help you are just being rude. I'm sorry, but I can't really appreciate that :(

Comment: @Allendar: the thing that - there is no issue. OP has no idea about performance optimizations and just woke up with a great "I want to optimize something" Monday idea. How do I know that? Well, if it wasn't the case - we would see results of profiling in the question. So your "help" is more harm than good since you're trying to convince the OP that they can "optimize" it (whereas they just shouldn't)

Comment: @Allendar: "2Mb is just a suggestion in my explanation, no fact" --- then probably it was not a good idea to tell "PHP memory won't lik e those", was it? Unless you can point to some reputable article or place in php MM sources that specifically state it "doesn't like it"

Comment: That's just plain rude and a way to try to make your point out rule mine. I hope the OP will find his/her answer. Bitching like that like an university professor doesn't help in any way either. Maybe you should recommend the OP to read the PHP source code and see how crappy it handles it's C pointers concerning the overflow of junk it overlays on each action the PHP interpreter performs. This topic is done for me. I'm off. I hope the OP finds what he/she needs.

Comment: @Allendar: telling "you don't need that" isn't rude. But it's silly to answer every pointless question on SO, instead of explaining that it's pointless. You haven't provided an answer though, just a random (and incorrect) thoughts, that are "helpful" indeed :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can gain more performance by NOT enclosing variables in double quotes.

```
include($file);
```

Other than that, I'd question the need to store code file names in the session, but this somehow might make sense.

Make sure to use an opcode cache for optimum performance. There is no real difference in using `include($var)` or `include('filename.php')`.

Comment: How can you answer his question without any prior knowledge of the files that are loaded? You don't know if the files are a few KiloBytes or 100's of MegaBytes. Depending on how he wants to use that data is very important in this matter.

Comment: @Allendar: it's a pretty acceptable generic answer. If they are the 100Mb files and you need to include them - then you just need to include them. And, no, it doesn't matter on "how he wants to use that data"